# Get indices of a character in a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

The problem I am trying to solve is this: I have a string, say, `"abcabcdefdefjhi"`. What I want the result to be is a numerical output like this:

```
a: 0, 3
b: 1, 4
c: 2, 5
.
.
.
```

P.S. The string is in Arabic but still be helpful to know how to do that for both Arabic and English.

Comment: Could you post the Arabic string as well as any code you've attempted so far?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Prune I am new to python, I tried converting the string to array of characters and then get the positions of characters but the problem for me is I don't know how to work with different encoding schemes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a line:

```
c = "abcabcdefdefjhi"
print "\n".join(["%s: %s" %( e, ", ".join([ str(j) for j, e2 in enumerate(c) if e2==e]) ) for i, e in enumerate(sorted(set(c)))])
```

1) List of not repeated:

```
sorted(set(c))
```

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'j']

2) List of positions by letter

```
[ (i, e) for i, e in enumerate(sorted(set(c)))]
```

> [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), ... , (6, 'h'), (7, 'i'), (8, 'j')]

3) Group positions by letter:

```
[( e, [ j for j, e2 in enumerate(c) if e2==e] ) for i, e in enumerate(sorted(set(c)))]
```

> [('a', [0, 3]), ('b', [1, 4]), ('c', [2, 5]), ..., ('i', [14]), ('j', [12])]

4) Reduced in one line

```
print "\n".join(["%s: %s" %( e, ", ".join([ str(j) for j, e2 in enumerate(c) if e2==e]) ) for i, e in enumerate(sorted(set(c)))])
```

> a: 0, 3
>
> b: 1, 4
>
> c: 2, 5
>
> d: 6, 9
>
> e: 7, 10
>
> f: 8, 11
>
> h: 13
>
> i: 14
>
> j: 12

Answer (score 0):

Use enumerate, like this:

```
def findOccurrences(s, ch):
    return [i for i, letter in enumerate(s) if letter == ch]


print(findOccurrences('abcabcdefdefjhi', 'a'))
```

Output:

```
[0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary of lists might be appropriate, mapping letters to a list of indices:

```
s = "abcabcdefdefjhi"
indices = {}

for i, l in enumerate(s):
    if l not in indices:
        indices[l] = []

    indices[l].append(i)

for k, v in indices.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(k, str(v)[1:-1]))
```

Output:

```
a: 0, 3
b: 1, 4
c: 2, 5
d: 6, 9
e: 7, 10
f: 8, 11
j: 12
h: 13
i: 14
```

Or, testing with `"لوحة المفاتيح ال"`:

```
ل: 0, 6, 15
و: 1
ح: 2, 12
ة: 3
 : 4, 13
ا: 5, 9, 14
م: 7
ف: 8
ت: 10
ي: 11
```

[Try it](https://repl.it/repls/EmbarrassedMenacingEquation).

Answer (score 0):

Easy try this:

```
 for index,i  in enumerate(s,0):
     print index, ':',i
```

output:

Answer (score 0):

Using *defaultdict* from *collections*

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = 'abcabcdefdefjhi' 
dd = defaultdict(list)

for i, v in enumerate(s):
    dd[v].append(i)

for k, v in dd.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, ', '.join(list(map(str,v)))))
```

> ```
> a: 0, 3
> b: 1, 4
> c: 2, 5
> d: 6, 9
> e: 7, 10
> f: 8, 11
> j: 12
> h: 13
> i: 14
> ```